# What should I do to use MFC dialogs from other libraries in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC ActiveX control project written in Visual Studio 2008 that contains a dialog box.  The dialog box is wrapped in a class, as is normal.  I want to use the dialog box in another project.  Since an ActiveX (.ocx) file is a DLL, I can merely use the ActiveX file as I would a DLL.

The problem I ran into is that the dialog box's class has this near the top:

```
// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CDeploymentDlg)
    enum { IDD = IDD_DEPLOYMENT };
```

`IDD_DEPLOYMENT` is defined in the OCX's `resource.h` file.  My current project also has a `resource.h` file.  When I build my current project, I get an error because `IDD_DEPLOYMENT` is missing in my current project's `resource.h` file.  My workaround was to copy the OCX project's `resource.h` file into a file named `DeploymentDlgResource.h` in my current project, and #include it before I #include the declaration for the dialog class.

This should work for now because I won't need any more dialog boxes in my current project.  But what would happen if I created a project that needed another dialog box?  What if that second dialog box also came from a separate library?  Do I always need to use duplicate resource files like this?  Do I have to worry about possible duplication of numbers used in them?

Comment: You can have duplicate resource IDs. In huge projects like I've worked on, it is impossible not to have them...at least for strings. You can get around the limitation by using AfxSetResourceHandle(). It's not too hard to write a stack based object that sets the resource handle to the one you want and then restores it when you're done.

Comment: Resource ID's need to be unique *per module* (and resource type). That's why all resource functions take an `HMODULE` (which is [the same as an `HINSTANCE`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903)) argument, like [CreateDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogw).

Comment: I will comment and say that if you have duplicate resource IDs in a module, the resource compiler will let you know...because you can't successfully compile with duplicate resources. However, in separate modules, it is easy to have duplicate resources and in that case you need to have a plan in either how to avoid having duplicates or how to manage the duplicates you do have.

Comment: Or, you have the option to leave the OCX as is and use it like an ActiveX as it was designed to. Merging the code into your project can be done, but then you'll have to redo the same steps each time the OCX is updated with new features or fixes.